# Tableau - Display measure names on rows rather than columns

Tags: tableau-api

Simple question, and new to Tableau.

I'm trying to display a simple table showing sales and margin by customer. For each customer, I need to display their name, customer number, and country on top of each column (one column per customer). This is fine, but the labels ("measure names") for name, account number and country are displayed on top of the table, rather than to the side (with a dash separating them).

Does anyone know how to move them to the side of the table? I've had a good look on the forums, but can't see an answer. I've attached a JPEG of what I'm trying to do. [Desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoMbv.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Could try creating a calculated field to concatenate the 3 separate fields.

On the menu bar:
1. Analysis -> Create Calculated Field
2. in the pop up enter in a heading such as "Concat Fields" and in the code window add:

```
[name]+", "+[customer name]+", "+[country]
```

3. Select okay

Drag this into your columns shelf before your other field and I think this should give you your desired output.

If you have to deal with null values please see this post:

https://community.tableau.com/thread/107679